# Same inner div image height as the outer

Tags: html, css

My inner image should have the same height as the outer div.

My code is:

```
<div>
   <div class="col_2_fifth">
      <figure>
         <img src="....." />
      </figure>
   </div>
   <div class="col_3_fifth">
      <div class="description">
          <p>....</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But the image height is always less than its parent div height.

What can i do now? Can i fix this with jquery/js or with css?

Comment: Check if the outer div has some padding attached to it?

Comment: this question already have an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19193308/4323504

Comment: Can you create fiddle for your issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize image to 100% height of a div and keep aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646740/resize-image-to-100-height-of-a-div-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

simply write:

```
figure img {height:100%:}
```

Comment: it doesnt cause any effect

Comment: check in firebug if your `<figure>` tag is taking height or not.. if not then give height first.

Comment: when you say "height as the outer", then which outer you are targeting exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <div class="col_2_fifth" style='width:20%'>
      <figure>
         <img src="123.jpg-17eqp8a.jpg" width='100%' />
      </figure>
   </div>
   <div class="col_3_fifth">
      <div class="description">
          <p>....</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You may add

```
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the css file responsible for the `col_2_fifth` and `col_3_fifth`. That will help you in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
.col_2_fifth {
padding : 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with CSS:

```
 .col_2_fifth {
      background: url(123.jpg-17eqp8a.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
```

This wil set the image as background for the div with the class col_2_fifth

link in comment from Luthando Loot is best solution

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.col_2_fifth, figure, figure img {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.col_2_fifth, figure img {
    height: 100%;
}
```